# A common request method with decoder passed as parameter in Flutter using Dio

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart, dio

Not sure if what I'm trying to do is a foolish en-devour or ? In the app, I use rest API calls and I'm trying to implement API handling with Dio.
I have gone with an approach like so.

each API method has a generic function. ie: the POST method. goes like

```
Future<dynamic> postRequest({String? endPoint, dynamic decoder, data}) async {
    // late String _fullURL = BaseOptions().baseUrl + endPoint!;
    late int? _responseCode;
    try {
      final response = await _dio.post(
        endPoint!, // APIEndpoints.postSignUp,
        data: data, //jsonEncode(data),
      );
      //
      // final String _responseString = response.data;
      _responseCode = response.statusCode;
      //
      if (_responseCode == 200) {
        final String _responseString = response.data;
        final res = decoder(_responseString);
        log("post success response ------------ ${res.toString()}");
        return SuccessHandler().checkSuccess(res);
      } else if (_responseCode == 201) {
        log("post success no response ------------ ");
        return HTTPResponse<dynamic>(
          false,
          null,
          message: 'empty success',
          code: _responseCode!,
          //'Something went wrong! Please try again in a moment!',
        );
      } else {
        log("post failed response ------------ ");
        return null;
        // return ErrorHandler().checkError(_responseCode, _responseString);
      }
    } on DioError catch (e) {
      // print(e.message);
      // throw Exception(e.message);
      log("exception ------------ ${e.message}");
      return HTTPResponse<dynamic>(
        false,
        null,
        message: 'error: ${e.message}',
        code: e.response!.statusCode!,
        //'Something went wrong! Please try again in a moment!',
      );
    }
  }
```

Where I try to pass the decoder to get the JSON response read out from the API response. Using a generated class like this

```
ValidateEmailModel validateEmailModelFromJson(String str) =>
    ValidateEmailModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String validateEmailModelToJson(ValidateEmailModel data) =>
    json.encode(data.toJson());

class ValidateEmailModel {
  ValidateEmailModel({
    this.email,
    this.type,
    this.code,
    this.expire,
    this.createdTime,
  });

  String? email;
  String? type;
  String? code;
  dynamic expire;
  dynamic createdTime;

  factory ValidateEmailModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      ValidateEmailModel(
        email: json["email"],
        type: json["type"],
        code: json["code"],
        expire: DateTime.parse(json["expire"].toString()),
        createdTime: DateTime.parse(json["createdTime"].toString()),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "email": email,
        "type": type,
        "code": code,
        "expire": expire!.toIso8601String(),
        "createdTime": createdTime!.toIso8601String(),
      };
}
```

In my method calls. i give the function its paramters like so

```
res = await APIHandler.instance.postRequest(
                endPoint: APIEndpoints.postValidateCode,
                decoder: validateEmailModelFromJson,
                data: {
                  "code": val,
                  "email": _email,
                },
              )
```

And await the response to be passed to another common method SuccessHandler() so I can get the data object/s

```
class SuccessHandler {
  dynamic successObject;

  SuccessHandler({this.successObject});

  Future<dynamic> checkSuccess(dynamic response) async {
    return SuccessHandler(successObject: response);
  }
}
```

so far when I try to debug the code. I do get the `response.data` from the `Dio` response. but gives me

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

can I achieve what I need to and how can I update the code? Please help me with this or just I think I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: can add the json response you are getting

Comment: how do you mean?

Comment: sorry my bad, try directly parsing json response because you are getting a json not string and `json.decode(str)` requires a string to convert it into json but you are already getting json so no need to use it

Comment: where can I update with this?

Answer (score 0):

`validateEmailModelFromJson` what this function will do is take a string convert it into json and will parse it you data model but in you `postRequest` function you are already get a json response from api call so no need to pass a decoder to you function.

where you are returning `SuccessHandler().checkSuccess(res);` directly return the `_responseString` so it should be like this,

```
 if (_responseCode == 200) {
        final String _responseString = response.data;
        log("post success response ------------ 
        ${_responseString}");
        return SuccessHandler().checkSuccess(_responseString);
      }
```

now try directly using `ValidateEmailModel.fromJson` on `_responseString`, you will get the data